# Is there an MFC Decompiler available?

Tags: decompiler, mfc

I want to know if there is already an MFC Decompiler?
So far, you have to decompile by hand - which is very tedious.
I would like a tool like DeDe Decompiler. The C++ code itself is not important. It is important to decompile the project architecture and generate the appropriate header and cpp files.

I really don't want to invent it myself. But, if there is no other choice - apparently - it will be necessary. Because already 3 projects are pending.

Comment: Not aware of such a tool. Also what version of MFC are we talking about? Statically linked or dynamically?